# A construction  of tensor product (Coutinho's book: D-module)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor-products

I am reading the book of Coutinho: A primer of Algebraic $D$-modules. In past, I usually study   commutative algebra, so I am a freshmen with non-commutative (Weyl) algebra? In Chapter 12 of the Coutinho book, he constructs tensor product of two modules as follows:

**Construction (page 109 of Coutinho's book)**

Let $R, S$ and $T$ be (general) rings. Let $M$ be an $R$-$S$-bimodule and let $N$ be an $S$-$T$-bimodule. We will define the tensor product of $M$ and $N$ over $S$, denoted by $M \otimes_SN$.

First consider the set of $M \times N$ of all pairs $(u, v)$ with $u \in M$ and $v \in N$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the free Abelian group whose basis is formed by the elements of $M \times N$. The elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are formal (finite) sums of the form
$$\sum_i a_i(u_i,v_i)  \quad (\star)$$
with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $u_i \in M$, $v_i \in N$. Note that this sum of pairs are mere symbols: the sum is not an element of the direct sum $M \oplus N$. In fact, if we assume that different indices correspond to different pairs in $(\star)$, then the sum is zero iff each $a_i = 0$. If $r \in R$ and $t \in T$, put 
$$r(u, v) = (ru, v)$$
$$(u, v)t = (u, vt).$$ 
These are well-defined actions that make an $R$-$T$-bimodule of $\mathcal{A}$. ...

**My question:** Is $\mathcal{A}$ an $R$-module?

**Example:** I consider $r=0$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an $R$-module then $0(u, v) = 0$. But in Coutinho's construction $0 (u, v) = (0u, v) = 1.(0, v) \neq 0$.

I also checked the construction of tensor product in the book "Homology" of S. Maclane, it is different from the Coutinho's one.

Comment: Why are you asking if it is an $R$-module if you've shown thar it isn't? :-)

Comment: I think $\mathcal{A}$ is not an $R$-module. But Coutinho claimed it is an $R$-module. 

Comment: This question is not appropriate for MO; it should be asked on math.stackexchange.com. $(0 \cdot u, v)$ is not equal to $1$. 

Comment: the author is not claiming that $(0\cdot u,v)=1$, not at all. He claims that $(0\cdot u,v)=1\cdot (0,v)\neq 0$.  

Comment: Oh. Then yes, it's clear that these aren't well-defined actions. For example, we also have $(r + s)(u, v) = ((r + s)u, v) \neq (ru, v) + (rs, v)$. The correct construction of the tensor product involves quotienting by the obvious relations first. I still don't think this is an appropriate question for MO. 

Comment: To construct the tensor product you need to take the free abelian group on $M \times N$ and divide by the subgroup generated by the elements $(us, v) - (u,sv)$. In this way you obtain an abelian group; the actions of $R$ and $T$ are obtained by functoriality.

Comment: Thank all of you for your comment. I now is more understanding the construction of tensor product. I have one more question. We consider commutative ring $R$. Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. The construction of $R$-module $M \otimes_RN$ often a bit different. For example: In Atiyah-Macdonald: An introduction to Commutative algebra they construct by take {\bf the free $R$-module on $M \times N$} and then modulo a certain submodule. Could you explain this different.  

Comment: What's important is the resulting tensor product, with its universal property. The constructions are just for proving its existence, they are never used in proofs.

Comment: @ Angelo: Thank you very much. I will delete my question in tomorrow.

Comment: To Pham Hung Quy: there no reason to delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should finish this question: $\mathcal{A}$ is not an $R$-module as Coutinho's claiming. The construction of tensor product should by taking a free abelian group $\mathcal{A}$ and then modulo a certain subgroup (see the comment of Angelo or S. Maclane: Homology, Chapter V). In the case commutative ring $R$, we can take $\mathcal{A}$ is a free $R$-module.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to also have a look at Bourbaki's Algebra (edition from 1970 or later), Chapter II, Section 3, especially Paragraph 4 (about multimodule structures on tensor products).